# Push Notification Changing Badge of AppIcon

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uiapplication

I am working on an app that can receive `Push-Notifications`.
When a notification is received, I need to change the number of the icon's badge and increment it.
Those notifications are stored in a `UITableView` in my app.
When a row is pressed, this means that the notification has been read so I want to decrement the badge.
I am new to push notifications and badges and I really couldn't find any efficient way to do it

any solutions ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't automatically increment a badge from a notification. Your notification payload must contain the `badge` property that will be set to the **exact value** you want for your badge.
To set the badge value from within your app, you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:someInteger];
```

If you want to increment the badge by one every time you receive a notification, you need to keep track of your user's badge server-side.
For example, if you send 3 notifications to an user, you will have a `badge` column in your database for this user with 3 as a value.  If the user opens his app and taps one of the notifications, your app will have to set the badge icon to 2 and send a request to your server to decrease the database value to 2.

**TL;DR:** There is no such thing as a `badge:+1` or `badge:autoincrement` in a notification's payload. You have to keep track of the badge's value server-side.